# Jenkins Slave node. how to display server URL in slave command line?

Tags: jenkins

I created a slave for jenkins. when I access the node from slave machine it shows 
Run from slave command line:

javaws http://localhost:8080/computer/Dimantha/slave-agent.jnlp

how to display IP address of master server instead of 'localhost'?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have encountered this issue before and here is the solution:

```
Manage Jenkins-->Configure System-->Jenkins Location
```

Then change the **Jenkins URL** to actual IP or hostname.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your master's configuration is probably set wrong.
In the Jenkins master configuration, you should edit `Jenkins URL` to the actual IP or hostname so it will be resolved correctly when accessing from a browser like in your example.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you're asking - since this is a command line, you just edit the command and replace localhost with your master server name.